# Backups seeming much much larger than my hard drive

Tags: backup

Can anyone explain this to me? My drive clearly does not have 140TB of backups on it...

[image]

this is on a late 2013 retina macbook pro 13 inch.

Comment: When Apple does it right it's nice, however when they do things like making the RGB values of Photos and Backups so close as to be indistinguishable it just makes one wonder what were they thinking! :(  Looking at the Macintosh HD in your photo I would think it should not be showing the same color all the way across as it is and should actual show white to the right side for over a third of it, based of the shown free space.  Wish I could offer you an absolute solution, alas I can't.  Is the Macintosh HD encrypted?

Comment: I think it might be encrypted, but the issue I'm having with this, is that it's stating that I have 140TB of data stored on my250Gb drive

Comment: What version of OS X and have you tried using Verify Disk etc. in Disk Utility to see if it clears it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a glitch in Time Machine. When an auto-backup is scheduled but your external hard drive isn't available, the computer saves a backup locally. I'm not exactly sure how their space-counting function manages to mess up like this, I'm just paraphrasing what I read in a Google result that then proceeded to give me the solution that worked for me.

The solution: Go into System Preferences > Time Machine, and flip the switch from on to off. Restart your computer, confirm that your storage usage looks reasonable again, and then you're free to go back and switch automatic backups on again.